# facebook connect setup issue

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add facebook connect to my online mafia game that I own.

When trying to add my domain name I get this:

```
Error  
App Domain: http://www.redhotglockz.com/ is not a valid domain.
```

It is valid cause I am logged in right now, the site is working fine.

I had to pay money to add this to my site, after purchase I go into my site control panel and into the newly available facebook connect option. It gave me an app name and game url and a link to facebook to create a new app. I followed this link and added the info as instructed, and result was invalid domain name. I used copy and paste to enter info. And url shown is correct.

Any idea how i can fix this?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i figured out my problem...

i was posting app domain as [www.ReDHoTGLoCKz.com](http://www.ReDHoTGLoCKz.com)

facebook wouldn't accept it using caps.

it worked using [www.redhotglockz.com](http://www.ReDHoTGLoCKz.com)

thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

check your facebook app configuration at https://developers.facebook.com/apps . make sure in basic setting, you set your App Domain with your url.

Comment: thanks for response od3n... but this is where i am having the problem... i enter my correct url and it says not a valid domain.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a domain, that's a URL.

Enter just `redhotglockz.com` and it should work fine.